# How can I extract a Ruby `instance_eval` invocation into a method?

Tags: ruby

I have this Ruby code for a Padrino application:

```
module Filters
  def self.authorize_admin
    proc { halt(401) unless current_user.admin? }
  end
end

App.controllers :secrets do
  before :show, &Filters.authorize_admin
  # ...
end
```

When the `secrets` controller receives a request on the `show` route, it will run the `authorize_admin` filter.

If I want this rule to apply to every route instead, I might write this:

```
before { instance_eval &Filters.authorize_admin }
```

I'd like to extract this to a method in `Filters` instead, so that I can just write:

```
before { Filters.only_administrators }
```

What's the right way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I wound up doing this:

```
module Filters
  def self.authorize_admin
    proc { halt(401) unless current_user.admin? }
  end

  def self.filter(controller, filter)
    filter_method = method(filter.to_sym)
    controller.instance_eval &(filter_method.call)
  end
end
```

and you now invoke it like:

```
Filters.filter(self, :authorize_admin)
```

Comment: I think if you remove the `proc { }` then you can use `instance_eval &filter_method`.

Comment: @maxpleaner I can't remove the `proc` because in other controllers I'll still want to use the `before ..., &...` style. I guess I could refactor those other controllers, though?